# Parse TimeSpan 1:00 and 01:00

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

i want to Parse a String of Hours for Example:
16:40, 01:00, 12:00, 1:00, 4:90

my Parsing way :

```
txtManDezStunden.Text = TimeSpan.ParseExact(txtManStunden.Text, "hh':'mm", null).TotalHours.ToString("0.00");
```

Everything works fine if the Input of txtManStunden.Text is 01:00
It "fails" when the Input is 1:00 which is a behavior i would like to catch.

Is there a way to still parse even if the Operator uses "01:00, 001:00, 1:00" as an input

Thanks for any recommendations

Comment: There's an override to provide multiple formats: try `TimeSpan.ParseExact(txtManStunden.Text, new []{"hh':'mm", "h':'mm"}, null)` to match single and double digit numbers of hours. I don't think this will work with triple digit hours though

Comment: @phuzi Pretty sure `hhh` isn't valid, in fact I don't think there's a way to parse `001:00`.

Comment: @DavidG already updated my comment ;o)

Comment: @Nico When you parse `001:00`, are you expecting that the `001` part is the total number of hours? Could that contain `123:00` for example?

Comment: Single `h` covers both `1` and `01`. `001` is indeed not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from @phuzi worked

I now use multiple Formats which it tries to Parse now works like a Charm.

TimeSpan.ParseExact(txtManStunden.Text, new[] { "hh':'mm", "hhh':'mm", "h':'mm", "h", "hh" }, null).TotalHours.ToString("0.00");

I cant Parse Hours Greater than 24 now, any way to fix it withouth breaking the current formating?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you can do, but it depends on whether you expect the hours component can be the total number of hours in the time span (e.g. the [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=net-5.0) property) and you could get an input of `123:00` to parse. Assuming that's not the case, then you can use the overload of [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=net-5.0) that takes multiple format strings, for example:

```
var input = "001:00";
var formats = new [] { "h':'mm", "'0'h':'mm" };
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, formats, null);
```

However, if you do need to parse `123:00`, then you will need to manually parse the string. Fortunately that is fairly simple to do by splitting the string up.

```
var input = "001:00";
var parts = input.Split(':');  
var hours = int.Parse(parts[0]);
var minutes = int.Parse(parts[1]);
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
```